# How I Can Integrate And Develop zkteco fingerprint scanner (reader) with project Asp Net Mvc5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, zkteco

I have a `zkteco slk20r` fingerprint reader, and I have web application `ASP.NET MVC5`,
Please I want to help me to define it to register the fingerprint for each user and the login authentication with it?

Comment: If it's a BioMetrix, then they have an sdk for that. Refer to link: https://github.com/zaagan/BioMetrix
For the structure,  it's too broad to answer in specific. But what you may do is to build a service which will communicate with an API.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i want full example or video to solve this problem
and what you mean by communication with API ? and how to get this API?

Comment: Check http://camsunit.com/application/javascript-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html if it helps. This is working with different scanner, but you can if your scanner can be implemented on the same way